# The new profile "Member for..'s" icon is unrelated

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page, images

The following icon in the new profile:

[image]

feels like a refresh icon in a browser's address bar, not a "member for.." icon. It does not represent that, I suggest an icon similar to the "users" icon in some SE sites, something like:

[image]

but with one person in the icon. I know it is way too silly to be considered, but just saying it.

Comment: There is a place to report bugs, still no need to start new report for each bug. (*If you find any bugs and have any feedback to give, please post these as answers to this post*)

Comment: @ShadowWizard wasn't aware of that post, I added an answer there (y).

Comment: Oh, didn't come to my mind someone can miss it. No harm done! :)